Mesh Deform dependency cycle and collision for blender 4.2+
i need ideas hot to fix mesh deform dependency cycle that dont works with collision.
What we want to achieve: character with jiggle physics and character's cloth being sim on top of that.
The Setup:
Character with armature with mesh deform modifier. Another mesh with cloth sim to simulate jiggle physics which is the target for mesh deform. Cloth over character.
How i always did it and had no problems:
I bake mesh with jiggle physics. Then turn on COLLISION on a character and then sim cloth over it.
But the things was working before 4.2 cames out and i simply cant sim cloth over character because as i turn ON COLLISION my mesh deform modifier automatically stop working so i cant sim cloth over character because it would not being affected by mesh deform.
I posted bug on blender forums but the devs said gtfo its not a bug fix dependency cycle.
i googled, checked console and it really has it. But i have totally dont understand how can i fix it. If i turn off any modifier nothing would work as planned.
On blender from 2.79 to 4.11 everything worked fine even with dependency cycle, yet on 4.2+ mesh deform modifier instantly falls in "cannot get mesh from cage object" error as i turn on collision on character.
Can any1 help fix this in blender 4.2+?
link below with blend file, where "icosphere" represent character, "deformer" is the jiggle physics and the cloth is the cloth that must collide with deformed mesh.
U can open it with older version than 4.2 and check that everything is working fine.
blend file, ~13mb
40 sec youtube video to observe the problem

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
